# Implement Launchdarkly with function in react without wrapping in Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, featuretoggle, launchdarkly

Currently I am following the guidelines provided by **launchdarkly** and as per documentation I used:

```
import { asyncWithLDProvider } from 'launchdarkly-react-client-sdk';
(async () => {
  const LDProvider = await asyncWithLDProvider({
    clientSideID: 'CLIENT_SIDE_ID',
    context: {
      "kind": "user",
      "key": "KEY",
      "name": "NAME",
      "email": "abc@example.com"
    },
  });
  render(
    <LDProvider>
      <ControllerPage />
    </LDProvider>,
    document.getElementById('reactDiv'),
  );
})();
```

This somehow create problem as it's not working properly .

Also this is not my requirement even if it work I don't want to wrap my read code with `<LDProvider></LDProvider>`.
So i am asking is there any solution for this problem that I can use **launchdarkly** implementation using function without Wrapping my code with `<LDProvider></LDProvider>` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done as :

**NPM Package :**

```
npm install launchdarkly-js-client-sdk
```

**Code :**

```
import * as LDClient from 'launchdarkly-js-client-sdk';

const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
const newUser = {
    "kind": "user",
    "key": `guest-user-${randomString}`,
    "name": `guest-user-${randomString}`,
    "email": `guest-user-${randomString}@email.com`
}
const ldclient = await LDClient.initialize('LAUNCHDARKLY_ID', newUser);
ldclient.on("ready", () => {
    const flagData = ldclient.allFlags();
    const flagResponse = flagData['feature_name']
    if (flagResponse != undefined && flagResponse) {
        //  Do this
    }else{
        // Do this
    }
```

Above code is used to evaluates all the flags. If you want to evaluate a particular flag then it would be like this  :

```
import * as LDClient from 'launchdarkly-js-client-sdk';

const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
const newUser = {
    "kind": "user",
    "key": `guest-user-${randomString}`,
    "name": `guest-user-${randomString}`,
    "email": `guest-user-${randomString}@email.com`
}
const ldclient = await LDClient.initialize('LAUNCHDARKLY_ID', newUser);
ldclient.on("ready", () => {
    const flagResponse = ldclient.variation('flag-key-123abc',false);
    if (flagResponse != undefined && flagResponse) {
        //  Do this
    }else{
        // Do this
    }
```

Above , false represents if somehow error occurred then what would be the default value one should use.

Comment: Thank you . I really in need of this and it's also working.

Comment: Is that .on("ready") a jQuery function?

Comment: No @WillLanni, it's launchdarkly hook.